# Moviepy creating videos with create date = 0

Tags: ffmpeg, moviepy

I am creating a video using `moviepy CompositeVideoClip`. After creation when I check its exif data it gives me Create Date of the video as 0000:00:00 00:00:00.
Is there a parameter to set the created date?

Comment: Since you tagged your question with the ffmpeg tag: if you're using the `ffmpeg` command-line tool you could use the `creation_time` metadata, such as `-metadata creation_time="2019-03-07T09:01:33-0900"` or `-metadata creation_time=$(date +%FT%T%z)` or `-metadata creation_time=now`.

Comment: Yes, but how to do it with moviepy. I tried adding **ffmpeg_params** to the write_videofile - `final_clip.write_videofile( "Video.mp4", fps=24, audio_codec="aac", ffmpeg_params=['-metadata', 'creation_time="2019-03-07T09:01:33-0900"'], temp_audiofile=str(userId)+"_audio.mp4")` .But it still dont work

Comment: I don't know. You used the [tag:ffmpeg] tag which is for ffmpeg questions: not for any third-party wrappers themselves that pollute this tag, so I assumed an answer directly dealing with the ffmpeg issue would suffice.